# A problem with IntStream in int[][], I don't know what allMatch() doing

Tags: java

After becoming famous, the [*CodeBots*](https://codebots.com/) decided to move into a new building together. Each of the rooms has a different cost, and some of them are free, but there's a rumour that all the free rooms are haunted! Since the *CodeBots* are quite superstitious, they refuse to stay in any of the free rooms, or any of the rooms below any of the free rooms.

Given a matrix, a rectangular matrix of integers, where each value represents the cost of the room, your task is to return the total sum of all rooms that are suitable for the *CodeBots* (ie: add up all the values that don't appear below a 0).

Example:
for:

```
matrix = [[0, 1, 1, 2], 
          [0, 5, 0, 0], 
          [2, 0, 3, 3]]
```

the output should be

```
matrixElementsSum(matrix) = 9
```

**Can anyone explain how `allMatch` works in this code?**

```
int matrixElementsSum(int[][] matrix) {
        return IntStream.range(0, matrix.length)
                .map(i -> IntStream.range(0, matrix[0].length)
                        .map(j -> IntStream.range(0, i)
                                .allMatch(k -> matrix[k][j] > 0)
                                ? matrix[i][j] : 0)
                        .sum())
                .sum();
}
```

Comment: There's documentation available for java, also [for allMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allMatch()` method takes an `IntPredicate` object. `IntPredicate` is a [Functional Interface](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/function/package-summary) whose "functional method" is `test(int)`. Your code passes all the elements to it and checks if all of them **match**  *>0*. You could also use `anyMatch()` method here. Then your code will be like this:

```
int matrixElementsSum(int[][] matrix) {
    return IntStream.range(0, matrix.length)
            .map(i -> IntStream.range(0, matrix[0].length)
                    .map(j -> IntStream.range(0, i)
                            .anyMatch(k -> matrix[k][j] == 0)
                            ? 0 : matrix[i][j] )
                    .sum())
            .sum();
}
```

Also, the ***time complexity*** of this algorithm is `f(i,j) = j.(i(i+1)/2) = O(j.i^2)` where `i` is the number of rows and `j` is the number of columns.

Comment: I can see that the number of matrix access is 11, while it should be 8 for either method. For beginners it might be a good idea to indicate that the time complexity is too high. I sincerely hope that that's the next lesson that the robots learn.

Comment: Oh, dear, and it goes over all x, y of course. Yipes.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
matrix = [[0, 1, 1, 2], 
          [0, 5, 0, 0], 
          [2, 0, 3, 3]]
```

Here's the matrix, program traverses every element(e.i. matrix[i, j]) in the matrix, `i` means current row, `j` means current column, and the statement decide whether the element should be added to sum is:

`IntStream.range(0, i).allMatch(k -> matrix[k][j] > 0)`

the statement means ALL the elements 'up' to current element should MATCH `>0` which means not free.

Answer (score 0):

```
function solution(matrix) {
   const numberOfRows = matrix.length;
   const numberOfCols = matrix.length * matrix[0].length;
   
   const sum = 0;
   const rooms = [];
   const hauntedRows = [];
   
   matrix.forEach((row, idx) => {
        row.forEach((item, cIdx) => {
            if(item === 0) {
                hauntedRows.push(cIdx);
                return;
            }
            
            if(hauntedRows.includes(cIdx)) {
                return; 
            }
            
            rooms.push(item)
        })
   })
   
   return rooms.reduce((prevVal, currentVal) => prevVal + currentVal, 0)
}
```

This is the solution I came up with.